# How to intersect users and tags?

Tags: support, tagging, search

I would  like to see all the  questions with a given tag that  user  xxx has asked or answered.
How do I do that?

**Edit**
I have received three fine explanations, more than completely answering my question. As often,  I am both grateful to the friendly users who wrote them and angry at the software which forces me to very unfairly "accept" just one. But fortunately  I can  upvote all of them...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is [the search page](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=) but it is not very helpful without further explanations, so let me walk you through the procedure that works best for me:

My goal is to find all questions that [Georges Elencwajg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3217/georges-elencwajg) answered in the [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis) category.

---

1. I go to [Georges's user profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3217/georges-elencwajg) (looking for the name on the users page [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users) if necessary):

   [image]

   You see that in the upper right corner the user number is automatically filled into a small search box, so you don't need to figure it out by other means.
2. I click into the search box which causes it to magically enlarge.

   I type  `[complex-analysis]` into the search box (the exact name of the tag
   inside square brackets — I could also add other tags in square
   brackets or further keywords):

   [image]
3. I hit the <kbd>return</kbd> key (or the <kbd>enter</kbd> key) and get [the list I'm looking for](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3217+[complex-analysis]):

   [image]

---

Alternatively, I could go to the [tags page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3217/georges-elencwajg?tab=tags) on Georges's user profile and click on the relevant tag which leads me immediately to [the same list](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3217+[complex-analysis]). But it takes as many steps to describe and is less flexible.

Comment: Dear t.b., as always when you explain something the answer becomes  blindingly clear. Thanks a lot for this perfect explanation .

Comment: Dear Georges, you're very welcome and thanks for the kind words! There's another, maybe somewhat safer, way which I added to the end of the answer. I hope that this short description is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

May be, by going to his user page and locating that tag you're looking for and clicking on it...

For instance:

- [All the questions in [tag:group-theory] that I answered are here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:21436+[group-theory])

The general format seems to be:

`https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:<user-id-goes-here>+[<tag-name-here>]`

Comment: Thanks Kannapan. But do you mean that I can't use the user's name and that I have to replace it by a number associated to him?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, unfortunately, we cannot use the user's name; only the user id can be used, if you're going to type the general url there. However, alternatively, you can go to his user page (which does not require user id) and locate the tag and click on it.

Comment: Thank you again, Kannapan.

Answer (score 2):

I've only seen one user in any user-specific queries, so here's an [adaptation](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+[homework]) of one of Bill D's links...

You search for "user:xxx [tag in brackets]"

Finding the user's number (for me at least) is easiest from their page... but once you're there, it would probably just be easiest to (as Kanna mentioned) click a tag from there.

Comment: Ah, yes, this works perfectly: thanks a lot, The Chaz. I don't quite understand what you mean by having seen only one user (Bill Dubuque) in any user-specific query. Kannapan gave an example with himself as user, didn't he?

Comment: Maybe I should have said that *I only knew that such was possible because of repeated exposure to (appropriately placed) links by Bill D*... You can put any user's number in there; I looked up the syntax in Bill's activity log.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up this matter, The Chaz.