# Can I search by UserName AND Tag? Eg: All my posts about series-seq?

Tags: support, search

Can I search by UserName AND Tag? Eg: All my posts about series-seq?

The search:  [sequences-and-series] user:JackOfAll 
returns 30,000 results! 
Not right.

Comment: See also: [How to intersect users and tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4051) and [How to search for postings of user X with tag Y?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21597)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's right. You can't use `user:JackOfAll`. What happens if you change your username?

Instead, you can search by a `userid`, which is the number you see in the search box when click on a user's profile.

If you're interested in your own posts, you can use `user:me` instead.